How would you proceed with this integration question?
Q1:
I am tasked to integrate the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k)$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dk}{k'K(k)^2}$$ where k is the elliptic modulus.
From this answer by Setness Ramesory you can see how Hilbert Transform is used to calculate these kinds of integrals.
Q2: Could there be a general form:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dk}{k'K(k)^n} |n>1$$
Edit 1
The motivation behind calculating this integral and the more general form is linking it to certain modular forms and their relations to elliptic functions.
Jamming the generalized integral into the machinery of Mathematica and trying for different n I get:
|n=1 -> 0.788675...
|n=2 -> 0.420724...
|n=3 -> 0.233478...
...
